# Already existing python file when open in visual studio code editor , code is not visible

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

when an existing python file is open in visual studio code editor 
code is not visible and also not recognizing as .py file

I have installed the python extension and setup the environment variables but still not working

I want the code to be visible

Comment: be more specific, context, post what you tried, what you need, errors etc See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you mean by “not visible”? Can you post a screenshot of VS Code with the opened file?